# Find a string between html tags in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that will pull out a string between two HTML tags within an HTML file. I don't know what the value will be, but I know what tags need to be searched. Additionally, I know that the tags do *not* always appear at the start of a line (i.e., they can be in the middle of a line of text). Finally, I also know that the tags and the string between them will never break across a line.

I have the path of the file stored in a variable

```
$filePath = "C:\Path\file.html"
```

I'm trying to find any value between `<h6>` and `</h6>` and store those values in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$myarray = gc $filepath | 
% { [regex]::matches( $_ , '(?<=<h6>\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+</h6>)' ) } | 
select -expa value
```

This remove starting and trailing spaces if any.
If you need also this spaces remove `\s+` from the regex pattern

Comment: Perfect! After posting this I played more with my regex and I almost had it like you have. One last question: What does the `select -expa value` do?

Comment: @EustaceMonk You can try the command without pipe to `select -expa value` and then try with pipe to `select value` to understand the difference. testing it is better than my english ;)

Comment: I don't see a difference between using `select -expa value` and leaving that completely off. I do see the difference when using just `select value`.

Comment: @EustaceMonk Without pipe to `select -expa value` retuns all matchinfo. pipe to `select  value` return an array of `pscustomobject`. pipe to `select -expa value` return an array of string